# CURL request with 'Connection: close' fails to load all of content

Tags: curl, nginx, tcp, http-headers

I have a server that defaults to sending HTTP/1.1 responses with "chunked" data. However, when I curl that server using "Connection: close" then it only seems to report the first 3-4 kilobytes of data.

I have clients that send that header - how do I make sure they get all the content from nginx + fastcgi before they close the connection to my server?

```
curl -v http://example.com -sL -H 'Connection: close'
```

Here is the example of the conversation curl records:

```
user@server:~$ curl -v http://example.com -sL -H 'Connection: close'
* About to connect() to example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 111.111.111.111... connected
* Connected to example.com (111.111.111.111) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> Connection: close
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Mon, 22 Dec 2014 20:15:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=if5b1f79ml57dogas9aqa3uq20; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< X-Expires-Orig: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
< {...3-4 kbytes of data ....}
<
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: server's using byte-serving, and you're not requesting the full range to be served...?

Comment: `Connection: close` has nothing to do with chunked transfer, nor would it cause the behavior your seeing.  Your application is probably sending a chunked response without properly chunking the data, causing the disconnect to occur once all the data has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

If that is truly what happens, it is simply the wrong behavior (on the servers behalf). [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) section 6.1 says

> The "close" connection option is defined for a sender to signal
> that    this connection will be closed after completion of the
> response.  For    example,
>
> ```
>  Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that
> the sender is going to close the connection after the current request/response is complete (Section 6.6).

The key there being *after* the response is *complete*.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the header exchange.

Comment: Possibly wiresharking the connection will help to pinpoint this better, but you will see that this isn't curl trying to close the connection. It does rather look like something is odd in the other end... but I can't tell exactly just based on this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is curl misbehaviour (need to say im using an old curl/7.15.5 which comes with RHEL5), you can workaround it by putting in the middle an Apache as proxy-server, it will replace the headers and the behaviour will be the expected.

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL6hV.png

In my environmente there is also an HAProxy server, which can also be interfering

> [...] haproxy adds a "Connection: close" header to the request forwarded to the server.
>   Unfortunately, when some servers see this header, they automatically refrain
>   from using the chunked encoding for responses of unknown length, while this
>   is totally unrelated.

But it also identifies curl as the client closing the connection early in the DATA phase.

There is also no problem using SOAP UI or other clients.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that `curl` has ran out of all of client port -- `netstat -nat` can print all the connection status, and I bet you'll find tons of `TIME_WAIT`, which means `curl` close the connection first.